# Dynamically "objectify" a nested data structure with python-attrs

Tags: pytest, python-attrs

With an arbitrary dictionary (eventually with nested collections and basic types), what is the best approach to make it a list of nested objects with python-attrs?

Some constraints: the dictionary keys are always strings (that are valid python identifiers) and its values will only contains native collection types, strings, ints and floats. And any nested dictionary at full depth will always have the same characteristics. In any list or tuple, all the items will be of the same type or None. And quite likely my dictionaries will always be ordered mappings, so the order should be preserved in the resulting top level list and in each nested mappings.

e.g. with:

```
{'some_key': [
  {'some_value': 12, 'foo': 'abc', 'bar': [1, 4, 8], 'baz': None}
  {'some_value': 24, 'foo': 'xyz', 'bar': [12, 12], 'baz': 'this'}],
 'other_key' : [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I would like to end up with a list of two objects that I can traverse using attributes:

```
some_key[0].some_value, some_key[0].baz 
other_key[-1]
```

i.e. this the result would be to "objectify" the nested mapping. How could I do this with attrs? is some loop with `attr.make_class()` calls the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I came up with a solution towards objectifying that is slightly different (and could be easily extended for this):

This is using `attr.make_class`. In my case "pluggy" plugin classes (pluggy is the plugin lib used and from `py.test`) are contributing new [data attributes](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/5784b20a5c4263a55b8efae0509767aca30caeea/src/scancode/plugin_info.py#L46) to a data [object](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/5784b20a5c4263a55b8efae0509767aca30caeea/src/scancode/resource.py#L688).
I then call [`make_class`](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/5784b20a5c4263a55b8efae0509767aca30caeea/src/scancode/cli.py#L694) to build a new subclass of my data class adding new `attr.ib` attributes to this subclass. I could have avoided instead declaring these attributes and built them on the fly from a recursive introspection  of the data types of contributed attributes.... but I went for explicit over implicit ;)

Along the way, there was a small [bug](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/339) on the way `attr.ib`s created outside of a class body may not be attached to a new subclass using the order I would expect and this was resolved ultra fast by @hynek

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why would you want to use attrs for that, because there is specific library for that purpose: [Box](https://pypi.org/project/python-box/)

```
from box import Box

a_dict = {'some_key': [
    {'some_value': 12, 'foo': 'abc', 'bar': [1, 4, 8], 'baz': None},
    {'some_value': 24, 'foo': 'xyz', 'bar': [12, 12], 'baz': 'this'}],
    'other_key': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

box_dict = Box(a_dict)

assert box_dict.some_key[0].some_value == 12
assert box_dict.some_key[0].baz == None
assert box_dict.other_key[-1] == 4
```

Answer (score -1):

It might help to state why you want to have objects instead of simply using dictionaries.  Your example usage is:

```
some_key[0].some_value, some_key[0].baz 
other_key[-1]
```

The difference would be:

```
some_key[0]["some_value"], some_key[0]["baz"]
other_key[-1]
```

Is the only thing you are looking for here to get the dot-access syntax?

`attrs` is mean to give you a way to define classes more simply, not as a way to wrap unstructured data into objects of a type that is not pre-defined, so this doesn't feel like a use case `attrs` that `attrs` is meant to address.

Comment: "Is the only thing you are looking for here to get the dot-access syntax?" : ..... yes and this is a valid API usability concerns for plugins creators. And this means eventually generating new types with attrs on the fly which I am doing alright now. I appreciate your attempt to find issues with the need in the first place, but I think this is a valid one and attrs is a valid way to go to this too!

Comment: FWIW, cattrs seems to address this too on top of attrs. Basically the problem is de/serialization on arbitrary nested data to/from objects which I like using using attrs for.

Comment: From the attrs docs: `if your dict has a fixed and known set of keys, it is an object, not a hash. So if you never iterate over the keys of a dict, you should use a proper class.` I think this is the justification.